# Reverse the string (IN PLACE) in python

Tags: python, in-place

I want to know how to reverse a string in python without creating a new one.

I can't seem to get it.

Comment: The answer is that you can't. Python is not low-level like c/c++ - it does not provide APIs to do so.

Comment: You can't change a string in place, let alone reverse it.

Comment: Python `str` objects are immutable.

Comment: When asked this question in Python/Java where it is not possible to reverse a String in place the *"String"* will usually be provided to you as array/list of characters so it is possible: https://repl.it/repls/CornyBuzzingConferences

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable, which means you can't really change it. There's no way you could reverse it in-place.

Obviously, you could reassign the same variable to it, but this is not an in-place change as you asked for:

```py
str = 'reverse'
str = str[::-1]
```